# Counting multiple null values over a table

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

I've done some research and for the most part the answers are all acceptable for small tables.  I'm working with a table that has about 25 columns.  What I'm wanting to do is count how many null values there are in the entire table.  From what I understand count() will count the row where the condition statement is true.  So for instance, given a table "some_table" with 12 rows and given the following statement:

```
Select Count(*) from some_table 
where condition = true
```

will return 12 (if each of those rows matches the condition) despite how many columns the table has.  Now if you were to count the null values for the given scenario you could do so if the table is small.  But what if it weren't?  How would you count multiple null values over the columns without making a mammoth of a query?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
Select
  sum(
    case when field1 is null then 1 else 0 end+
    case when field2 is null then 1 else 0 end+
    case when field3 is null then 1 else 0 end+
    ...
    case when fieldN is null then 1 else 0 end
  )
from
  some_table 
where
  condition = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I think this might do it.  I wasn't having success with the case function earlier but I think I was using it incorrectly.

EDIT:

I just checked it out.  This will work.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE
   null_sum NUMBER := 0;
   null_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR aCol IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE') LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE condition = true AND '||aCol.COLUMN_NAME||' IS NULL' INTO null_count;
      null_sum := null_sum + null_count;
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table SOME_TABLE has '||null_sum||' NULLS');
END;
```

Instead of doing a loop for each column you can write a single dynamic statement using DBMS_SQL package but this is more effort to code and worth only if you are concerned about performance.

Edit: found an even better one without multiple SELECTS's:

```
DECLARE
   cols VARCHAR2(1000);
   null_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR aCol IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE') LOOP
        cols := cols||'NVL2('||aCol.column_name||',0,1)+';
   END LOOP;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SUM('||REGEXP_REPLACE(cols, '\+$')||') FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE condition = true' INTO null_count;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'null_count = ' || null_count );
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    count(*) - count(col1) col1_nulls,
    count(*) - count(col2) col2_nulls,
    count(*) - count(col3) col3_nulls,
    ...
from
  some_table
where
  condition = ...
```

or

```
select
    12*count(*) - 
      count(col1) - 
      count(col2) -
      ...
      count(col12)
from
  some_table
where
  condition = ...
```